# SQL Server - Select últimos 7 dias a partir do último registro

Tags: sql-server, query, select

Galera sou iniciante em SQL e tá complicado de resolver esse problema que surgiu.. Preciso de um select no SQL-Server que retorne: as vendas dos últimos sete dias.

Por exemplo se o último dia em que houve venda, foi no dia 10/04/2019, então a query deverá mostrar as vendas entre o dia 04/04/2019 e 10/04/2019.

A lógica creio eu que esteja correta, porém não sei os comandos adequados para fazer esse select... Valeu ai quem puder me auxiliar!! :D

```
SELECT * FROM vendas
    where ven_data <= max(ven_data)
    and ven_data >= max(ven_data - 7)
```

Comment: Seria com base no dia atual? Tipo hoje - 7?

Comment: Não, seria a partir do último produto vendido. Por exemplo se a última venda foi no dia 10/04/2019 então o resultado seria entre o dia 04/04/2019 e 10/04/2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta do *Daniel Mendes* está correta, mas daria para fazer um pequeno ajuste na query.

Não tem necessidade de fazer `ven_data <= @max_ven_data` pois a `@max_ven_data` já é a maior possível. Então para todos os registros da tabela a condição `ven_data <= @max_ven_data` seria verdadeira. Ou seja, daria para simplificar a query dessa forma:

```
select * from vendas
where ven_data >= (select dateadd(day, -6, max(ven_data)) from vendas);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Essa resposta também foi de grande valia para meu código, e ainda diminui 1 linha. Grato :)

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo o seu exemplo, você pode fazer esse filtro no `where`, utilizando um `subselect`:

```
select *
  from vendas
 where ven_data <= ( select max(ven_data) from vendas )
   and ven_data >= ( select dateadd(day, -6, max(ven_data)) from vendas );
```

Utilizei o `max` para obter a ultima venda e novamente o `max` para obter a data de sete dias antes da última venda, com o auxílio da função `dateadd`.

***Obs.:** Coloquei -6 na subtração da data para ficar como seu exemplo, pois dia 10 - 7, seria 3, mas pelo seu exemplo, você quer o dia posterior a esse, isso também pode ser alterado quanto ao `>=` na condição do `where`, mantendo assim 7 na subtração mas a condição fica somente `>`*

---

> Veja esse exemplo online: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/680e7/3

---

> Documentações:
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.. Através dessa resposta, consegui solucionar o problema. Grato :)